# Udemy JS form submission exercise

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events, document

I'm working on a Udemy course from an instructor named Colt Steel. I'm stuck on creating a form submission. Here are his instructions:

Form Events Exercise

Time to get some practice working with forms and form events! index.html already has a form element that contains two  elements, one for quantity and one for a product name.  index.html also contains an empty ul where you will append new li's.

Listen for the form submission

When the form is submitted, prevent the default behavior

Grab the quantity input value and the product input value

Create a new li element. Set the text on the new li to include the quantity and product name from the form.

Append the new li to the ul on the page

Reset the inputs

**And here is the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Grocery List</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
    <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <form action="/nowhere">
        <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
        <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
        <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is what I have so far

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const product = document.querySelector('#list');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    const userform = form.elements.userform.value
    const userqty = form.elements.userqty.value
    
    const newForm = document.createElement('li')
    
}) 

**Edit: Here is the gif of what it is supposed to look like when completed**

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQeMQ.gif
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fair enough. My code is in complete and/or just wrong. I'd like help w/ that regarding a const variable I could be missing. Or mislabeling something. I hope that clarifies my needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to referring the wrong attribute **name**. As in HTMl the first input box, the argument **name** is **product** but in Script, you are referring to **userform**.

In order to create/add a new item List to parent ul, You'll have to create a new Element and append the new Child to parent Element.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const product = document.querySelector('#list');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const product = form.elements.product.value;
  const quantity = form.elements.qty.value;

  // Get the Parent ul
  const parentList = document.querySelector('ul#list');
  // Create a new li Element
  let newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  // Create a new TextNode Element to add data and Append to li Element
  newListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${quantity} ${product}`));
  // Append the li to parent ul Element
  parentList.appendChild(newListItem);

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Grocery List</title>
  <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
  <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Grocery List</h1>
  <form action="/nowhere">
    <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
    <input type="text" id="product1" name="product">
    <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" id="qty1" name="qty">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>

  <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```